# Write a function called cube that takes a parameter n

Tags: javascript

How do I write a function called cube that takes a parameter n. The function should multiply n times n times n (“cubing” n, or n to the 3rd power, mathematically speaking). The result of that multiplication should be returned at the end of the function (so that if this function was called, the answer for “n cubed” would be returned to the part of the program that called the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
function cube(n) {
    return n * n * n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why you need to write this function at all? Just use regular javascript syntax.

```
const cubed = n**3
```

Or for older syntax, the actual function already exists on `Math`

```
const cubed = Math.pow(n, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extremely simple function:

```
function cube(n) {
    return cube ** 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function cube(n) that takes a number, n, and cubes it and returns a string in the form Cube of (n) is (n cubed). For example, cube(4) returns Cube of 4 is 64.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).